# Decode Chunked (gzip deflate) data using c# or jquery

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, gzip, deflate, chunked

I am consuming a web-service and I am getting Chunked Data. The data is Unicode character and showing as expected in browser. But, after fetching data, I need to store it to database as Unicode char as it display in browser.

I tried different options and nothing was successful.
Below is the sample of data:

I want to save this to database as it show in browser. Not as chunked.

Here are the headers value:

Content-Type: application/json

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Hope someone can help me.
Thank You
Ben

-----Sample Chunked Data starts here------------------ 
സൃഷ്ടിക്കുന്നു</span>\r\n1</span> ആദിയില്‍ ദൈവം ആകാശവും ഭൂമിയും സൃഷ്ടിച്ചു. 2</span> ഭൂമി രൂപരഹിതവും ശൂന്യവുമായിരുന്നു. ആഴത്തിനുമുകളില്‍ അന്ധകാരം വ്യാപിച്ചിരുന്നു. ദൈവത്തിന്റെ ചൈതന്യം വെള്ളത്തിനുമീതെ ചലിച്ചുകൊണ്ടിരുന്നു. 3</span> ദൈവം അരുളിച്ചെയ്തു: വെളിച്ചം ഉണ്ടാകട്ടെ. വെളിച്ചം ഉണ്ടായി. 4</span> വെളിച്ചം നല്ലതെന്നു ദൈവം കണ്ടു. അവിടുന്നു വെളിച്ചത്തെ ഇരുളില്‍നിന്നു വേര്‍തിരിച്ചു. 5</span> വെളിച്ചത്തിനു പകലെന്നും ഇരുളിനു രാത്രിയെന്നും പേരിട്ടു. സന്ധ്യയായി, പ്രഭാതമായി  ഒന്നാംദിവസം.

-----Sample Chunked Data end here------------------

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your "record" delimiter is normal CRLF (\r\n)  But I am puzzled by the mismatched tags.  A ton of  tags without the leading  tag.  Also, how does the sample show in the browser?

Comment: &#3384;&#3395;&#3383;&#3405;&#3359;&#3391;&#3349;&#3405;&#3349;&#3393;&#3368;&#3405;&#3368;&#3393;&lt;/span>\r\n1&lt;/span> &#3334;&#3366;&#3391;&#3375;&#3391;&#3378;&#3405;&zwj; &#3366;&#3400;&#3381;&#3330; &#3334;&#3349;&#3390;&#3382;&#3381;&#3393;&#3330; &#3373;&#3394;&#3374;&#3391;&#3375;&#3393;&#3330; 364;&#3405;&#3364;&#3391;&#3368;&#3393; &#3370;&#3349;&#3378;&#3398;&#3368;&#3405;&#3368;&#3393;&#3